# Half-Life Deathmatch order

Tags: half-life-2, half-life, half-life-deathmatch

Does the Half-Life: Deathmatch and Half-Life 2: Deathmatch go in any order or are they just literally a deathmatch with no meaningful story?

I want to know before I begin playing the series

Comment: Yup, they're literally deathmatch with no meaningful story.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Half-Life 2: Deathmatch (and the original Half-Life deathmatch multiplayer mode) have no canonical connection whatsoever to the plot of the Half-Life series.

They are simply there to let you beat random people on the internet with crowbars.